# How to set title of Button using ReactiveKit Bond?

Tags: ios, reactivekit, swiftbond

Is there an equivalent of rac_liftSelector in Reactivekit to implement selector for setTitle?

Comment: If you could explain what you want to achieve and describe rac_liftSelector I might be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by creating a ReactiveExtension.

```
extension ReactiveExtensions where Base: UIButton {
        var Title: Bond<String?> {
            return bond { button, text in
                let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text!)
                button.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
        }
    }
```